# Selenium HTTP client calls CdpEndpointFinder with missing method?

Tags: java, kotlin, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium with Kotlin.  (I'm still new to both.)  I am getting the above error when I try to connect to a site.  (It's a trivial page for testing.)

My `settings.gradle.kts` file (relevant portions):

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.8.1")
    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools:4.0.0-rc-1")

    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.14.1")

    // Some library required log4j, but wasn't installing it as a dependency. So, manual.
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.21.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.21.0")
    testImplementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.21.0")

}
```

My code (simplified example):

```
val driverLocation = "/path/to/chromedriver"

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverLocation);

val options = ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*")
val driver = ChromeDriver(options)

// It dies on this line.
driver.get("https://www.garfieldtech.com/ip.php")
```

The full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpEndpointFinder.getHttpClient(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory, java.net.URI)'
```

Sure enough, if I click through in my IDE to `ChromeDriver`, the IDE calls out the `getHttpClient` method on this line is not defined:

```
reportedUri.map(uri -> CdpEndpointFinder.getHttpClient(factory, uri));
```

It feels like some kind of version mismatch, but I would expect the build system to catch that and warn me of an incompatibility.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are mixing up different Selenium library versions. In fact, you do not need `devtools` and `selenium-chrome-driver` dependencies. Just use the `selenium-java` one and that will pull all the dependencies.
Furthermore, version 4.6.0 introduced [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/), so you can skip pointing to the driver executable's location, the manager will download the right one based on your browser version.
Also, if you can use Java 11, with the latest version of Selenium (4.14), I believe, due to [this change](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9b35af2814ffe92c62f323ffe1d344fe19a296b1) you can skip adding the `--remote-allow-origins=*` argument.

So you can simplify your code to:

```
val driver = ChromeDriver()
driver["https://www.garfieldtech.com/ip.php"]
```